# cannot find symbol when compiling java

Tags: java, javac

I have few classes in the same package demo, but the most important are Server.java and MyServerImpl.java. In Server.java I have this code

```
package demo;

public class Server
{public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
        {
MyServerImpl s = new MyServerImpl("blablabla");
...
}
```

And the class MyServerImpl

```
package demo;

public class MyServerImpl extends MyServerPOA {

        private String location;

        public MyServerImpl( String location )
        {
            this.location = location;
        }

        public void add ( String value ){
            System.out.println("name " + value + location );

        }
            }
```

When I try to compile with javac I have this error

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MyServerImpl
location: class demo.Server
            MyServerImpl s = new MyServerImpl("blablabla");
```

I try to compile with this command `javac project/demo/Server.java`  and when I am in the demo folder
`javac Server.java` but still get the same error

Comment: compile `MyServerImpl` first.

Comment: What happens when you compile from folder project?

Comment: I really think this error message should be renamed. Nobody except software engineers that know what a compiler is understand that a "symbol" is a "token". Better error messages = less SO questions.

Comment: I have exactly the same error when I am in the folder demo and project.@Braj When I try to compile MyserverImpl i have the same error fro MyServerPOA who is in the same package too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment:

When `javac` looks for classes, the folders it looks in are based off of the *fully qualified* name for the class.

So in your case, the fully qualified name for `MyServerImpl` is `demo.MyServerImpl`. Thus, when the compiler encounters `MyServerImpl` in `Server.java`, it looks for a folder called `demo`, and if it finds that folder, looks for `MyServerImpl.java`.

If you `cd`'d *into* demo, this will cause compilation to fail, because `demo` obviously doesn't contain itself (otherwise you might have some broken OSs).

So what you need to do is `cd` into the folder *above* `demo`. So for example, if your file hierarchy is `src` as root, with the `demo` package inside, with `Server.java` and `MyServerImpl.java` inside:

1. `cd` into `src`, so that if you `ls`/`dir`, `demo` is (one of) the folder(s) that shows up
2. `javac demo/Server.java`
3. Done (hopefully)